# How to automate the execution of several inter-dependent Python scripts

Tags: python, linux, automation

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I have a collection of Python scripts, where:

- the first script acquires keyboard input, performs modifications to it, and stores the modified output in a file
- the second script reads the output generated by the first script and acquires (additional) keyboard input, performs manipulations, and stores some result in a second file
- etc.

For the sake of concreteness, let's say I have two Python scripts *1_script.py* and *2_script.py*, whose source codes are given below (at the end of this post).

I would like to know how I could run a single command in the terminal which performs all of the following actions:

1. executes *1_script.py*
2. provides 'hello' when *1_script.py* asks for keyboard input
3. executes *2_script.py*
4. provides '!' when *2_script.py* asks for keyboard input

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have to offer in this regard.

*1_script.py*

```
"""
This script:
    1) prompts the user to enter a string
    2) performs modifications to the entered string
    3) stores the modified string into a file 
"""

# get user input
user_entry = raw_input('Enter a string: ')

# perform modifications to the input
modified_data = user_entry + '...'

# store the modified input into a file
f = open('output_from_1_script.txt', 'w')
f.write(modified_data)
f.close()
```

*2_script.py*

```
"""
Dependencies:
    1) before executing this script, the script 1_script.py
        has to have been successfully run

This script:
    1) reads the output generated by 1_script.py
    2) modifies the read data with a user-supplied input
    3) prints the modified data to the screen
"""

# reads the output generated by 1_script.py
f = open('output_from_1_script.txt', 'r')
pregenerated_data = f.readline()
f.close()

# modifies the read data with a user-supplied input
user_input = raw_input('Enter an input with which to modify the output generated by 1_script.py: ')
modified_data = pregenerated_data + user_input

print modified_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a directory where you can store all the files
You may use module system or include every function into the same file
go to the directory and execute the mainfile.py defined below

1_script.py

```
"""
This script:
    1) prompts the user to enter a string
    2) performs modifications to the entered string
    3) stores the modified string into a file 
"""
def get_input():
    # get user input
    user_entry = raw_input('Enter a string: ')

    # perform modifications to the input
    modified_data = user_entry + '...'

    # store the modified input into a file
    f = open('output_from_1_script.txt', 'w')
    f.write(modified_data)
    f.close()
```

the next script will go in the next file

2_script.py

```
"""
Dependencies:
    1) before executing this script, the script 1_script.py
        has to have been successfully run

This script:
    1) reads the output generated by 1_script.py
    2) modifies the read data with a user-supplied input
    3) prints the modified data to the screen
"""
def post_input():
    # reads the output generated by 1_script.py
    f = open('output_from_1_script.txt', 'r')
    pregenerated_data = f.readline()
    f.close()

    # modifies the read data with a user-supplied input
    user_input = raw_input('Enter an input with which to modify the output     generated by 1_script.py: ')
    modified_data = pregenerated_data + user_input

    print modified_data
```

The third script
mainfile.py

```
from 1_script import get_input
from 2_script import post_input

if __name__=='__main__':
    get_input()
    post_input()
    print "success"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

When I read your reply, I realized I did not phrase my question very clearly - what I really wanted was to avoid having to type in the keyboard input manually each time but, thanks to your reply, it just dawned on me that I can modify your functions `get_input()` and `post_input()` so that each accepts one input argument (and call them accordingly in `mainfile.py`).

Thanks again - I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @A1dvnp happy to know it helped